# How to give extra space using live code

Tags: livecode

I have a scrolling field. It's containing some text and special characters like (---,'',.,",) e.t.c. I want add a single space before every special characters.Is it possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I d not know how long your text is, but you can:

```
  on mouseUp
get fld "yourField"
put "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" into normalChars
repeat for each char tChar in it
  if tChar is not in normalChars then put space & tChar after temp
  else put tChar after temp
end repeat
put temp into fld "yourOtherField"
end mouseUp
```

Now this assumes that all non-letter chars are "special" chars. Can you modify the handler to go the other way? That is, to identify only certain chars, rather than identify all non-letter chars?

Craig Newman

Answer (score 0):

ya. Please use this code

```
replace "--" with " --" in field "yourField"
replace "---" with " ---" in field "yourField"
```